# How do I create a loop in Python 3.3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want my program to ask the user if he wants to use it again (i.e. restart). How do I do that in Python 3.3?

I tried this

```
loop=1
while(loop==1):



    #code



loop-=1
    done=0
    while(done==0):
       choice=input("Do you want to restart?(Y/N)")
       choice1=choice.upper()
       if(choice1=="Y"):
           loop+=1
           done=1
           print("Restarting...")
       elif(choice1=="N"):
           done=1
           print("The program will now END. Thank you for using the program.")
```

Comment: GIYF http://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for http://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#while

Comment: and what is your problem?

Answer (score 3):

```
while 1:
    main()
    if input('Continue? [y/n]') == 'n':  # Ideally you would check they actually entered y or n
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're looking for something like `do...while` which doesn't exist in Python.

A replacement for this construct ("run at least once, repeat until a condition is met") can be constructed like this:

```
abort = False
while not abort:
    # do stuff
    exit = input("Exit [Y/N]? ").lower()
    if (exit ==  "y"):
        abort = True
```